# How get all beans having @Path annotations in quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

I have a requirement to get all the beans having @Path annotation.I can see the method.Arc.container().beanManager().getBeans(Type var1, Annotation... var2). Could anyone guide to pass the right arguments to get the beans.

Note: In spring boot I used: applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(RestController.class)

Regards,
Abel

Comment: have you tried using reflection? that's how Spring does most of it's magic internally after all

Comment: I used like :Set<Bean<?>> beans = Arc.container().beanManager().getBeans(MyController.class) ,it worked for specific controller. but in generic approach not able to find the exact arguments

Comment: CDI allows finding beans dynamically based on their types and qualifiers. Since `@Path` is not a qualifier, the dynamic lookup API will not work. You can find _all_ beans (e.g. `Arc.container().select(Object.class)` and then iterate through them and look at their annotations (not just qualifiers, all annotations, that should be possible). It's gonna be slow, but you only need to do it once... (A truly Quarkus native way would be to write a Quarkus extension that collects the beans at build time and exposes the list to runtime e.g. through bytecode recorder. I suppose that's overkill for you.)

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What is the end goal?